# How to recover journal superblock on mdadm RAID5 array

Tags: ext4, raid, mdadm, fsck

Yesterday my raid5 array with 3 disks was suddenly unmounted. After examining it, it seemed it had become degraded and one of the disks had a much lower event count than the rest.

I started running: `sudo mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sd[bcd]1` - however, I made a mistake: at the time I ran the command, the `/dev/sdb` disk was named `/dev/sde`, so the command was run against `/dev/sdc1` and `/dev/sdd1` only. The command reset the lowest event count disk to the highest count of the two (it was a diff of 600 events, I think). Which surprised me, as in the past IIRC, `--force` would not reset the event count for large diffs.

In the end, I ended up syncing the remaining disk (which was not the one with the lowest event count) with `sudo mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1`, as I've had to do a few of times in the past. The syncing finished after a couple of hours as expected, without errors. But ever since then, I've not been able to mount the array.

Here are the details of this system:

OS:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

RAID array

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Apr  4 23:46:03 2019
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 1953257472 (1862.77 GiB 2000.14 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976628736 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Feb  6 13:16:05 2020
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : pc:0  (local to host pc)
              UUID : 96c2bb9a:8318792c:843e1e85:820cd123
            Events : 21280

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       5       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       4       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       3       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
```

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid5 sdc1[4] sdd1[3] sdb1[5]
      1953257472 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 0/8 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Relevant part of `lsblk -f`:

```
sdb                                                                                                      
└─sdb1                  linux_raid_member pc:0 96c2bb9a-8318-792c-843e-1e85820cd123                  
  └─md0                 ext4              RaidData 88936c12-1664-4d4d-9d33-8aabd1efe0ab                  
sdc                                                                                                      
└─sdc1                  linux_raid_member pc:0 96c2bb9a-8318-792c-843e-1e85820cd123                  
  └─md0                 ext4              RaidData 88936c12-1664-4d4d-9d33-8aabd1efe0ab                  
sdd                                                                                                      
└─sdd1                  linux_raid_member pc:0 96c2bb9a-8318-792c-843e-1e85820cd123                  
  └─md0                 ext4              RaidData 88936c12-1664-4d4d-9d33-8aabd1efe0ab
```

Relevant output from the [lsdrv](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Asking_for_help#lsdrv) tool:

```
PCI [ahci] 00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
│
├scsi 1:0:0:0 ATA      WDC WD10EZEX-08W
│└sdb 931.51g [8:16] Empty/Unknown
│ └sdb1 931.51g [8:17] Empty/Unknown
│  └md0 1.82t [9:0] MD v1.2 raid5 (3) clean, 64k Chunk {None}
│                   Empty/Unknown
├scsi 2:0:0:0 ATA      WDC WD10EZRZ-22H
│└sdc 931.51g [8:32] Empty/Unknown
│ └sdc1 931.51g [8:33] Empty/Unknown
│  └md0 1.82t [9:0] MD v1.2 raid5 (3) clean, 64k Chunk {None}
│                   Empty/Unknown
└scsi 3:0:0:0 ATA      WDC WD10EZEX-00K
 └sdd 931.51g [8:48] Empty/Unknown
  └sdd1 931.51g [8:49] Empty/Unknown
   └md0 1.82t [9:0] MD v1.2 raid5 (3) clean, 64k Chunk {None}
                    Empty/Unknown
```

RAID member status:

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bcd]
/dev/sdb:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1953521664 sectors at         2048 (type 83)
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1953521664 sectors at         2048 (type 83)
/dev/sdd:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1953521664 sectors at         2048 (type 83)
```

Error while trying to mount, not sure what the error means:

```
sudo mount /dev/md0
mount: /media/dpm/Dades: mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning.
```

Superblock seems to be corrupted?:

```
sudo e2fsck -v /dev/md0
e2fsck 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
Journal superblock is corrupt.
Fix<y>? cancelled!
e2fsck: The journal superblock is corrupt while checking journal for RaidData
e2fsck: Cannot proceed with file system check

RaidData: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

I'm not too sure what `fsck` will do or if it's safe to run it at this point. Any advice will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Was sdb1 the disk with the much lower event count? Is mdadm --add the only command you ran? --examine is for member devices, not md devices, so no raid superblock on md0 is normal.

Comment: use copy-on-write overlay for experiments https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Recovering_a_failed_software_RAID#Making_the_harddisks_read-only_using_an_overlay_file

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated the description to answer both questions. I'm hoping it doesn't mean having executed a destructive action.

Thank you for the link to the copy-on-write overlay method. I see a long evening of reading ahead of me...

Comment: I'm afraid it means just that... forcing an older drive back into the array and overwriting the newer drive with it is not good at all. Nothing you can do about it now, other than hope for the best. Run the fsck on the overlay, either it mounts or it flummox completely; if nothing else helps you might have to scrape with photorec and see what's left.

Comment: I've given the overlay a go, but it seems running the `parallel 'size=$(blockdev --getsize {}); loop=$(losetup -f --show -- overlay-{/}); echo 0 $size snapshot {} $loop P 8 | dmsetup create {/}' ::: $DEVICES` command to set up the loop and overlay fails with `device-mapper: reload ioctl on sdb1  failed: Device or resource busy`

Comment: You can use /dev/md0 as device ... in this case your raid is running and fsck-on-overlay is the experiment. If you want to go under the md level you have to --stop the running array first

Comment: I manually defined `$DEVICES` as `/dev/md0` and then ran the overlay creation commands from the wiki. I then ran `e2fsck -v /dev/mapper/md0`, which fixed the journal superblock and fixed/deleted a bunch of i-nodes. I finally mounted `/dev/mapper/md0` and at a glance, I can access the original files from the overlay. I believe this means success! Feel free to post an answer pointing out to the overlay instructions and I'll be happy to mark it as the solution. Thanks!